# Feature file setup in cucumber

Tags: cucumber

I have two questions about cucumber frame work.
1-My .features files are not converting into feature format and showing as plan text file even though it works fine and I can run my TestRunner. 
2- I have saved my all TestRunner files into a package Runner but in TestRunner file I have to give full path of my feature file in order to run TestRunner. e.g features= "Features" not working but 
features="C:\Users\FourStar1\eclipse-workspace\com.freeTourTest\src\main\java\Features2\Addusers.feature"
works.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a careful look at the casing of your directory and package names. It's important you are consistent with these. It makes it easier to spot mistakes. Using lowercase is recommended.

Additionally tests and test resources should be put under `src/test/java` and `src/test/resources` respectively. Feature files are resources and will not be copied over `target` if you put them under `java`.

I would suggest learning the maven project layout by heart. It makes everything easier then making up your own organization.